# How to make such (filtered) tables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say for a table like this:

[image]

I can filter it like this:

How do I create tables in another sheet to get the following:

[image]

ect

And I hope it would be automatically updated as I have more entries of the data in "sheet1".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The result you describe can be achieved with several techniques.

First and foremost I'd advise you to turn your data into an Excel table by clicking any cell in the data range  and the Insert > Table.

Now you can build pivot tables from the table and use filters to show only the file names where column A is Y, and another pivot table where you use a filter to show only file names where column B is Y.

[image]

When you use an Excel table for the data input, you can add more data to the table. Then click the pivot table and click Refresh on the ribbon to include the new data in the pivot table.

Another approach might be to use Advanced Filter, but it is not as dynamic as the refresh option of a pivot table.